# How to autoresize UIToolBar?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitoolbar

I want the toolbar to automatically appear on the bottom of the screen, and I want it to resize the width so it adjusts from iPhone to iPad. The code below results in a static UIToolbar which stays in the same position. How do i make the toolbar appear at the bottom, and how do i adjust the width automatically according to screen size ?

```
- (UIView*)commomOverlay
{


UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,430)];


CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen   mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44); /*
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    rect = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1004);
}
UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
FrameImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[view addSubview:FrameImg];
[FrameImg release];*/

rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 50);



UIToolbar *myToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[myToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Finish" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexiSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:@selector(myFunction)];
mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (123,350,40,20)];
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleFlash:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
UIBarButtonItem *switchBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mySwitch];
//Order of how buttons appear or toolbar left to right.
[myToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: cancelButton, flexiSpace,switchBtn, nil] animated:YES];
 myToolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;


[cancelButton release];
[flexiSpace release];
[switchBtn release];

[view addSubview:myToolBar];
return view;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it's frame using a constant value. However, your view's frame is already set at this point and it will not change according to your autoresizingMask. You should use the view's bounds property instead and do something like:

```
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50);
```

Another option would be defining constraints for your view.